# flask sqlalchemy does not insert a foreign key using mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm using Flask sqlalchemy to create some tables for a database using mySQL. I have a problem when setting some foreign keys,

the tables are:

```
class Specific(db.Model):
    code = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True, index=True)
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True, index=True)
    equipment_id = db.Column(db.String(30), db.ForeignKey('general.id'), index=True)
    #setting relationship fields
    tickets_equip_code = db.relationship('Ticket', backref='specific_code', lazy='dynamic')
    tickets_serial_number = db.relationship('Ticket', backref='specific_serial, lazy='dynamic')
    

class Ticket(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True)
    solicitant = db.Column(db.String(30), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True, unique=False)
    #setting the foreign keys
    equipment_code = db.Column(db.String(30), db.ForeignKey('specific.code'), nullable=False)
    equipment_serial_number = db.Column(db.String(30), db.ForeignKey('specific.serial_number'), nullable=False)
```

the problem comes when I try to create all the tables using `db.create_all()` in the console, I get the following error:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError 1822 "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_ticket_serial_number' in the referenced table 'specific'"
```

I have other db Models with FKs but they seem to work well these two models are the ones causing the trouble but I can't get it. I've even tried to run the script using only one of the two FKs in the mentioned models and it runs fine; I have also tried setting both the primary keys in the `Specific` model using `__table_args__`, also I tried setting manually the FK constraints in `Tickets` using `__table_args__` (that's why the name 'fk_ticket_serial_number' appears) but it had no effect.
Do you guys have any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you try adding an index?

Comment: yeah, that's why the `code` and `serial_db` have the parameter `index=True`